# R Plotly 3d trace -- how to get new labels (not x, y, z)

Tags: r, plotly

Consider this example taken from Plotly:

```
library(plotly)
# volcano is a numeric matrix that ships with R
p <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>% add_surface()
p
```

Notice how if you hover, there's a nice trace that shows x (row indices from your matrix), y (column indices), and z (matrix content at given row and column).  How could I change the trace *and* the axes to something like "Measure1", "Measure2", "Measure3" instead of x,y, z?  I've tried `layout()` but what I put isn't cutting it.  This is what I attempted, but "zaxis" isn't a thing, and the other labels don't change,

```
library(plotly)
# volcano is a numeric matrix that ships with R
p <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>% add_surface() %>% 
layout (xaxis = list(title = "Measure1", showgrid = F),  
  yaxis = list(title = "Measure2"),
  zaxis = list(title="Measure3")
)

p
```

I'm sure I'm missing something elementary, but I'm stuck.  Any help warmly received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extend the previous answer from user2510479:

You can set the axis labels for Plotly surface plots via `scene` and `xaxis`/`yaxis`/`zaxis` `title`.

The hoverinfo can be set via `text` which needs to be an array which has the same dimensions as your z-values. `hoverinfo` needs to `text` in order to show those values.

[image]

```
library(plotly)

txt <- array(dim=dim(volcano))
for (x in 0:dim(volcano)[[2]] - 1) {
  for (y in 0:dim(volcano)[[1]] - 1) {
    txt[1 + x*dim(volcano)[[1]] + y] = paste('Measure1: ', x, '<br />Measure2: ', y, '<br />Measure3: ', volcano[1 + x * dim(volcano)[[1]] + y])
  }
}
p <- plot_ly(z = volcano,
             text = txt,
             hoverinfo = 'text') %>% add_surface()
p <- layout(p, scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "Measure1"), 
                            yaxis = list(title = "Measure2"), 
                            zaxis = list(title = "Measure3")
                            )
            )

p
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  p <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>% add_surface() %>% 
  layout(title = "Layout options in Volcano plot",
  scene = list(
  xaxis = list(title = "Measure1"), 
  yaxis = list(title = "Measure2"), 
  zaxis = list(title = "Measure3")))

  p
```

Comment: That helps, and gets me halfway there!  What about the trace function (the box that pops up when you hover over and shows you x,y,z coordinates)?

Comment: Something like this: http://codepen.io/etpinard/pen/RGJpoO (but I don't know how to reproduce this in R)...